# .NET Core and MS Access "migration" connection

Tags: c#, ms-access, .net-core, odbc

I'm using .NET Core 2.1 as a web application and need to setup a page to migrate older `.mdb` Access files into the new SQL Server database. It's not a single Access database.... its hundreds of user owner databases.

I have this installed: `AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe`

This nuget install:

```
using System.Data.Odbc;
```

32/64 bit Access drivers are listed in ODBC32 and ODBC64 but .NET Core is 64bit only from what I understand.

BUT... I can't get past this error which throws the exception on

```
connection.Open();
```

> OdbcException: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

My code:

```
public MigrateAccessDb(List<string> Files)
{
    //string file = Files[0];
    string file = @"D:\test.mdb";
    string connectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb, *.accdb)}; Dbq=" + file;
    //string connectionString = String.Format("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = {0}; Persist Security Info = False; ", file);
    //string connectionString = String.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = {0}; Persist Security Info = False;", file);

    string queryString = "SELECT * FROM Configs";

    using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
    {
        OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(queryString, connection);

        connection.Open();
```

Made a simple .net core console app.. same error:
[image]

Looping through multiple connectionStrings
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spaces are significant in an ODBC connection string.

The *Data source name not found and no default driver specified* error only occurs if you don't have a driver with a matching name and matching bitness.

The proper ODBC connection string for Access is:

```
"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; Dbq="+ file;
```

You were missing a space between `Driver` and `(`

Note that installing both the 32-bits version and 64-bits version of the Access Database Engine isn't really supported, and tends to lead to trouble. I know the space is a problem, but there might be others in your exact setup.

Comment: WOW... that was it exactly!  This is what stinks about coding on your own... no second set of eyes.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\myAccessFile.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;
```

[Reference](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/)

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: Any other example of connection strings?

Comment: added a new screenshot... looping through all provider examples I can think of.

Comment: If you exit VS, and launch the ODBC data sources from the control panel, can you create a FILE dsn to connect to Access? Your error message is the EXACT same one you get when you don't have x64 bit drivers installed. So, launch the ODBC data sources from the control panel (that will launch x64 one as opposed to the x32 one). Try creating a FILE dsn, and see if the accDB driver option is offered. If the accDB driver option is NOT given, then you don't have the 64 bit version of the ACE data engine installed. Try a test project, force it to x86 - your code will work, but as x64 it will not.

Comment: When I open the 64 bit ODBC and choose File Dsn -> Add.  It does have the mdb/accdb provider listed.  Same name as my provider string.  I even went into add/remove programs and deleted all "access" installations.  I had a 2010 redis, a 2013 Access something.  Right night I have the 2016 Access Database engine installed (64bit).  This also installs v10 32 bit access drivers too.

Comment: I know Jet/OleDb isn't supported in .net core, but from what I read, ODBC should work.  I can make a SQL connection thru VS but that is JET4.0 which wont work obviously.

Comment: "Try a test project, force it to x86" -- x86 project would work I agree since it would use .NET4x.  .NetCore is 64bit only.

Comment: I even tried `"DNS=test"` and setup a system 'test' ODBC entry (under 32 and 64).  Same error.